# How to connect nodeJS docker container to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have problems to connect a nodeJS application which is running as a docker container to a mongoDB. Let me explain what I have done so far:

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID    IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS        NAMES
3a3732cc1d90    mongo:3.4    "docker-entrypoint..."   3 weeks ago    Up 3 weeks    27017/tcp    mongo_live
```

As you can see, there is already a mongo docker container running.

Now I'm running my nodeJS application docker container (which is a build from meteorJS):

```
$ docker run -it 0b422defbd59 /bin/bash
```

In this docker container I want to run the application by running:

```
$ node main.js
```

Now I'm getting the error

```
Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment
```

I already tried to set MONGO_URL by setting:

```
ENV MONGO_URL mongodb://mongo_live:27017/
```

But this doesn't work:

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongo_live:27017] on first connect
```

So my question is how to connect to a DB, which is - as far as I understand - 'outside' of the running container. Alternativly how do I set up a new DB to this container?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do it.

- run your app in the same network as your mongodb:

  ```
  docker run --net container:mongo_live your_app_docker_image

  # then you can use mongodb in your localhost
  $ ENV MONGO_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/
  ```
- Also you can link two containers:

  ```
  docker run --link mongo_live:mongo_live you_app_image ..
  # Now mongodb is accessible via mongo_live
  ```
- use mongodb container ip address:

  ```
  docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' mongo_live
  # you will get you container ip here

  $ docker run -it 0b422defbd59 /bin/bash
  # ENV MONGO_URL mongodb://[ip from previous command]:27017/
  ```
- You can bind your mongodb port to your host and use host's hostname in your app
- You can use `docker network` and run both apps in the same network
- You could pass `--add-host mongo_live:<ip of mongo container>` to docker run for your application and then use `mongo_live` for mongodb url
- You can also use [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to make your life easier ;)

...

Comment: I am using docker compose, but not for this case. Let me explain: Here it is part of a CI workflow. Therefore I'm running docker build using a dockerfile: `docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:test -f Dockerfile.test .`. So I don't know how to use docker compose in this setting...

Comment: Docker compose can also build an image, You can also call run with compose which may help to run tests. There is also `--abort-on-container-exit` option which is also useful to run tests in CI. for example: https://github.com/mobilityhouse/prometheus-bridge/blob/master/Jenkinsfile#L78

Comment: I have posted a docker-compose solution below, i am sure u can use that as reference and figure it out

Answer (score 1):

When you run containers each container works in independent network. Because one container cant connect to other point to point.

The are 3 ways to connect containers

1. Have a little fuss with low-level docker [network magic](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network/)
2. Connect container through localhost. Each container must expose ports on localhost (as your mongo_live). But you need add to host ile on localhost `127.0.0.1 mongo_live` (**This is the simplest way**)
3. Use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/). It convenient tool for working many containers together. (**This is right way**)

Add mongodb to application container is not docker way.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below snippet for your docker-compose.yml file, replace comments with your actuals. Should solve your problem.

```
version: '2'
    services:
      db:
        build: <image for mongoDB>
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"  # whatever port u r using
        environment:
          #you can specify mondo db username and stuff here
        volumes:
          - #load default config for mondodb from here
          - "db-data-store:/data/db" # path depends on which image you use
        networks:
          - network
     nodejs:
        build: #image for node js
        expose:
          - # mention port for nodejs
        volumes:
          - #mount project code on container
        networks:
          - network
        depends_on:
          - db

networks:
  network:
    driver: bridge
```

Please use the below links for references : 
1) [NodeJs Docker](https://www.distelli.com/docs/tutorials/build-and-deploy-nodejs-with-docker/) 
2) [MongoDb docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/mongodb/) 
3) [docker-compose tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

I had problem how to connect my server.js to mongodb. And that's how i solved it hope you find it useful.
[Tap For My Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N4uS.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31038653)