# Connecting to Mongodb docker container from another docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I am trying to connect mongo DB running in docker container from another docker container where my node js code is running.

So I run MongoDB docker using the following command:

```
docker run --name my-local-mongo -v mongo-data:/data/db -p 27017:27017 -d mongo
```

I can access from browser typing `0.0.0.0:27017`, however when I try to connect from node js code I am getting following error. My url variable is:

`var url = "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/surveydb";`

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [0.0.0.0:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect **ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:27017**]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/usr/src/appg08/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/usr/src/appg08/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/appg08/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect nodeJS docker container to mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43962012/how-to-connect-nodejs-docker-container-to-mongodb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to link container in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768157/how-to-link-container-in-docker)

Answer (score 4):

```
var url = "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/surveydb";
```

is ip adddress is in your nodejs container only, so you should know what is ip address of mongo container or assign to ip address gateway of containers.

```
var url = "mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/surveydb";
```

or

```
var url = "mongodb://ipaddressofmongocontainer:27017/surveydb";
```