# Docker : impossible connection between MongoDB and another docker app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm having an issue with the connection between my MongoDB that I launched with docker (`port:27017`) but when I try to launch my app (the DB is needed for launching it), I am stuck with this error : `MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`.

I tried the solution at [Connecting to Mongodb docker container from another docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417322/connecting-to-mongodb-docker-container-from-another-docker-container) but sill could not figure how to solve this issue...

Anyone have a thought about this issue ?

```
docker run chat-ui       

                        -------------

__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\____/\\\\____________/\\\\____/\\\\\\\\\_____
 _\/\\\/////////\\\_\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\__/\\\///////\\\___
  _\/\\\_______\/\\\_\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_\///______\//\\\__
   _\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\/__\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\___________/\\\/___
    _\/\\\/////////____\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\________/\\\//_____
     _\/\\\_____________\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_____/\\\//________
      _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\___/\\\/___________
       _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_
        _\///______________\///______________\///__\///////////////__


                          Runtime Edition

        PM2 is a Production Process Manager for Node.js applications
                     with a built-in Load Balancer.

                Start and Daemonize any application:
                $ pm2 start app.js

                Load Balance 4 instances of api.js:
                $ pm2 start api.js -i 4

                Monitor in production:
                $ pm2 monitor

                Make pm2 auto-boot at server restart:
                $ pm2 startup

                To go further checkout:
                http://pm2.io/


                        -------------

pm2 launched in no-daemon mode (you can add DEBUG="*" env variable to get more messages)
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: [PM2] Starting /app/build/index.js in cluster_mode (0 instance)
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: App [index:0] starting in -cluster mode-
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: App [index:0] online
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: App [index:1] starting in -cluster mode-
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: App [index:1] online
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: App [index:2] starting in -cluster mode-
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: App [index:2] online
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: App [index:3] starting in -cluster mode-
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: App [index:3] online
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: [PM2] Done.
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: ┌────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name     │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0  │ index    │ default     │ 0.3.0   │ cluster │ 19       │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 61.7mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 1  │ index    │ default     │ 0.3.0   │ cluster │ 26       │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 52.9mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 2  │ index    │ default     │ 0.3.0   │ cluster │ 33       │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 51.0mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 3  │ index    │ default     │ 0.3.0   │ cluster │ 44       │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 45.3mb   │ root     │ disabled │
└────┴──────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: [--no-daemon] Continue to stream logs
2023-06-19T09:18:59: PM2 log: [--no-daemon] Exit on target PM2 exit pid=8
09:18:59 0|index  | Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000
09:18:59 1|index  | Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000
09:18:59 2|index  | Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000
09:18:59 3|index  | Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000
09:19:29 0|index  | MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
09:19:29 0|index  |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:277:38)
09:19:29 0|index  |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
09:19:29 0|index  |     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
09:19:29 0|index  |   reason: TopologyDescription {
09:19:29 0|index  |     type: 'Unknown',
09:19:29 0|index  |     servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
09:19:29 0|index  |     stale: false,
09:19:29 0|index  |     compatible: true,
09:19:29 0|index  |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
09:19:29 0|index  |     localThresholdMS: 15,
09:19:29 0|index  |     setName: null,
09:19:29 0|index  |     maxElectionId: null,
09:19:29 0|index  |     maxSetVersion: null,
09:19:29 0|index  |     commonWireVersion: 0,
09:19:29 0|index  |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
09:19:29 0|index  |   },
09:19:29 0|index  |   code: undefined,
09:19:29 0|index  |   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
09:19:29 0|index  | }
09:19:29 1|index  | MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
09:19:29 1|index  |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:277:38)
09:19:29 1|index  |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
09:19:29 1|index  |     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
09:19:29 1|index  |   reason: TopologyDescription {
09:19:29 1|index  |     type: 'Unknown',
09:19:29 1|index  |     servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
09:19:29 1|index  |     stale: false,
09:19:29 1|index  |     compatible: true,
09:19:29 1|index  |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
09:19:29 1|index  |     localThresholdMS: 15,
09:19:29 1|index  |     setName: null,
09:19:29 1|index  |     maxElectionId: null,
09:19:29 1|index  |     maxSetVersion: null,
09:19:29 1|index  |     commonWireVersion: 0,
09:19:29 1|index  |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
09:19:29 1|index  |   },
09:19:29 1|index  |   code: undefined,
09:19:29 1|index  |   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
09:19:29 1|index  | }
09:19:29 2|index  | MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
09:19:29 2|index  |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:277:38)
09:19:29 2|index  |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
09:19:29 2|index  |     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
09:19:29 2|index  |   reason: TopologyDescription {
09:19:29 2|index  |     type: 'Unknown',
09:19:29 2|index  |     servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
09:19:29 2|index  |     stale: false,
09:19:29 2|index  |     compatible: true,
09:19:29 2|index  |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
09:19:29 2|index  |     localThresholdMS: 15,
09:19:29 2|index  |     setName: null,
09:19:29 2|index  |     maxElectionId: null,
09:19:29 2|index  |     maxSetVersion: null,
09:19:29 2|index  |     commonWireVersion: 0,
09:19:29 2|index  |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
09:19:29 2|index  |   },
09:19:29 2|index  |   code: undefined,
09:19:29 2|index  |   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
09:19:29 2|index  | }
09:19:29 3|index  | MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
09:19:29 3|index  |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:277:38)
09:19:29 3|index  |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
09:19:29 3|index  |     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
09:19:29 3|index  |   reason: TopologyDescription {
09:19:29 3|index  |     type: 'Unknown',
09:19:29 3|index  |     servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
09:19:29 3|index  |     stale: false,
09:19:29 3|index  |     compatible: true,
09:19:29 3|index  |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
09:19:29 3|index  |     localThresholdMS: 15,
09:19:29 3|index  |     setName: null,
09:19:29 3|index  |     maxElectionId: null,
09:19:29 3|index  |     maxSetVersion: null,
09:19:29 3|index  |     commonWireVersion: 0,
09:19:29 3|index  |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
09:19:29 3|index  |   },
09:19:29 3|index  |   code: undefined,
09:19:29 3|index  |   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
09:19:29 3|index  | }
```

I tried using an online DB but I was still getting an error (`MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed`) because I wanted it to launch on my server, I didn't wanted to spend too much time on this solution (even in the case it would be working, which was not the case).

I tried using `mongodb://myip:27017` instead of `mongodb://localhost:27017` yet, still having an issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `localhost` in your container, It doesn't mean your PC, in the context of a container `localhost` means the container itself. The services inside a container runs in an isolated environment.
So that's why the container `chat-ui` unable to connect with the `mongodb` container with `localhost:27017`.

The way to connect different containers

- You can use [Docker Networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/). As this allows containers to communicate with each other in a network.
- OR you can deploy multiple containers by using [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)
- There is another approach for container linking with [Legacy container links](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/). But this is not recommended as it may eventually be removed

Also see these

- [How to get Docker containers to talk to each other while running on my local host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093812/how-to-get-docker-containers-to-talk-to-each-other-while-running-on-my-local-hos)
- [How to link containers in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768157/how-to-link-containers-in-docker)

Hope this will help you to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Have you exposed the mongo container's 27017 port to your host?

Try running the mongo container with either:

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 --name some-mongo -d mongo:tag
```

or:

```
docker run --network="host" --name some-mongo -d mongo:tag
```